# Where has WhatsApp gone?

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

WhatsApp was updating on my phone, but then I got a message so interrupted the update.

WhatsApp then disappeared from my home screen. When I go to WhatsApp in the App Store I am prompted to open, but nothing opens.

How can I get the app back?

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your phone. Then the app must bear visible on the springboard.

Comment: A hard restart could fix the problem : hold the home button and the power button until you see the apple logo

Answer (score 0):

It could  be due to the interruption caused during the update process, sometimes it also goes into infinite updating loop. You can try hard resetting your iPhone, this will not delete your content though, follow these steps -

1. Press and hold the Home button and the Sleep/Wake button simultaneously.
2. Hold both buttons until the iPhone powers down and restarts.

Then try downloading the app again..

OR

In case your iPhone has around 3-4 gb of space left you can try this method, it basically clears the cache data from your storage. Even I perform this once a week, it also helps to free some space. Here are the steps -

1. Open up iTunes
2. Search for a movie which is around 5-6 gb in size, (Lord of the rings)
3. Click on the rent button and just wait for a while the app clears the cache data.